# Word shuffle algorithm (PHP or javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, shuffle, cpu-word

currently im working on a game and I'm progressing quite well.
The problem is my shuffle algorithm. A word should be shuffled with randomness
 but **MUST NOT shuffled in its original wordform**. Example: "table" -> "table"
I want something like this: "table" -> "tlabe"

The first and last letter should stay at its place but the rest can be shuffled randomly except to its original wordform.

Currently i am using this function i wrote:

```
function shuffle_word($word)
{
    if(strlen($word) < 2)
        return $word;
    else
        return $word{0} . str_shuffle(substr($word, 1, -1)) . $word{strlen($word) - 1};
}
```

You can check out my game so far and get a better idea of it:
[WordShuffle - The Game](http://wordshuffle.bplaced.net/)

(Sorry the words are german at the moment, because I am german and testing it with friends make it easier)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Store the shuffled word in a variable and compare it to your `$word`. If they are the same, shuffle again.

Comment: The word often shuffles in its original wordform. I dont want that, it musnt happen otherwise there is nothing to guess.

Comment: Obvious first problem might be that you're shuffling bytes, not characters; nor do you have any checking to see if the shuffle has returned the same order of bytes

Comment: @MrDarkLynx that sounds very helpful and simple. Thanks i will test it

Comment: And of course if the original word was __3__ characters long, then the middle character could never be shuffled to a different position

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do it would be to split all the characters using [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php), then shuffle the obtained array using the [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function then [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array and you got your word shuffled !
Sample code:

```
function shuffle_word($word) {
   $chars = str_split($word);
   shuffle($chars);
   if(implode("", $chars) == $word) return shuffle_word($word);
   return implode("", $chars);
}
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the fast answers. I fixed the algorithm by checking in a while loop if the shuffled word is equal to the non shuffled word.

Comment: That's a horrible fix.